# Javascript - Capturar src por class name

Tags: javascript

Como capturar o atributo *src* de uma imagem com uma *class name* x?

por exemplo:

```
var Image = document.getElementByClassName("Picture");
console.log(Image.src)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode ser feito dessa forma:

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('Picture');
console.log(image[0].src);
```

O que você está errado é chamada da função getElementByClassName que está escrita de forma errada faltando o 's' de 'Elements', e o fato dessa função retornar um array com todos os elementos que ela encontrar com o nome de class especificada no argumento passado, assim também ao invés de capturar o valor da String src da imagem estava tentando acessar uma propriedade src do array, onde essa propriedade não existe.

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Me ajudou um milhão!!!